# Independence of sample mean and variance through covariance

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I have seen the text book derivation where the independence is established through factoring the joint distribution. But has anyone tried to prove that the covariance is zero?.

Let $Z_{i}$ come from a standard normal distribution.

Let $X = \bar{Z}$ be the sample mean and let $$Y = \sum_i\frac{1}{n-1} (Z_{i} -\bar{Z})^2$$ be the sample variance.

Prove that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$ .

I am getting terms like E($\bar{Z}^3$) in the expansion which is making it very cumbersome to handle...

Comment: By symmetry of an odd function, $E\left[\bar{Z}^3\right] = 0$ for a standard normal distribution.

Comment: It happens that the simplest (and most illuminating) way to prove that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated is to show that they are independent...

Comment: ^ yes I understand ... but it turned out to be very convenient that the JDF/MGF was obtained and could be factored for the normal dist

Comment: The title of your question "Independence of sample mean and variance through covariance" concerns me a bit.  Are you trying to establish that $X$ and $Y$ are independent by showing that their covariance is zero?

Comment: ^ I was... but I realize thats a wrong approach.

Comment: For the more general case (without assuming Normality), see:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942810/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First show that
$$
\operatorname{cov} (\bar{Z}, Z_i - \bar{Z}) = 0.
$$
These two random variables are not just normally distributed, but *jointly* normally distributed, since both are linear combinations of the same sequence of independent normals.  Therefore, they are uncorrelated only if they're independent.

Hence the sample variance, which is a function of $Z_i-\bar{Z}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, is independent of the sample mean.

**Later addendum:** I should add that the whole vector $(Z_1- \bar Z,\ldots,Z_n-\bar Z)$ is independent of $\bar Z$, since the covariance between $\bar Z$ and that vector is a matrix whose every entry is $0$ and we have joint normality.  If $(Z_1- \bar Z,\ldots,Z_n-\bar Z)$ is independent of $\bar Z$, then $((Z_1- \bar Z)^2+\cdots+(Z_n-\bar Z)^2$ is independent of $\bar Z$.

Comment: Sorry but $\bar Z$ and $Z_i-\bar Z$ being independent for every $i$ (as you recall) does NOT imply that a function of $(Z_i-\bar Z)_i$ (such as $Y$) is independent on $\bar Z$.

Comment: I've added a comment that it's the whole vector whose entries are $Z_i - \bar Z$ that is independent of $\bar Z$.  That is enough to justify the conclusion.

Comment: Why vector $(Z_{1}-\bar{Z} \dots Z_{n} - \bar{Z})$ and $\bar{Z}$ are independent ?

Comment: @openspace : First note that the covariance between $\overline Z$ and $Z_i-\overline Z$ is $0.$ Then observe that $\big(Z_1-\overline Z, \ldots, Z_n-\overline Z, \overline Z\,\big)$ is a tuple of JOINTLY normally distributed random variables. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy jointly because of their independence?

Comment: @openspace : You have $$Z_1-\overline Z = \left( 1 - \frac 1 n\right) Z_1 - \frac 1 n Z_2 - \cdots - \frac 1 n Z_n. $$ Thus this is a linear combination of $Z_1,\ldots, Z_n$ with constant (i.e. non-random) coefficients. And the same is true of $Z_i-\overline Z$ for $i=1,\ldots,n.$ Every tuple of linear combinations, with constant coefficients, of independent normally distributed random variables $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ has a multivariate normal distribution, i.e. its components are jointly normally distributed.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the random vectors $Z=(Z_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$ and $-Z=(-Z_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant n}$. Then $X=\xi(Z)$ for a given odd function $\xi$ and $Y=\eta(Z)$ for a given even function $\eta$. The function $\zeta=\xi\cdot\eta$ is odd as well, hence $\xi(-Z)=-\xi(Z)$ and $\zeta(-Z)=-\zeta(Z)$. 
Now, $Z$ and $-Z$ follow the same distribution, hence $\xi$ and $\zeta$ being odd functions yields that $\mathrm E(\xi(Z))=\mathrm E(\zeta(Z))=0$. In particular, the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is $\mathrm E(\zeta(Z))-\mathrm E(\xi(Z))\mathrm E(\eta(Z))=0$.

To sum up, the result you ask a simple proof of (that the empirical mean and empirical variance are uncorrelated) has nothing to do with gaussianity since it holds for every *symmetric* distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation... I understand what you say now but I accepted Michael's answer as it was more direct

Comment: +1, especially because it is not necessary to assume the $Z_i$ are independent or uncorrelated, but I have a suggestion and a minor question.  Suggestion: it is not obvious why $Z$ and $-Z$ follow the same distribution, and so perhaps the statement about symmetric distribution should be moved to the beginning. Minor question: The expectation of an odd function of a random variable might be undefined rather than being $0$. So, should the proof be expanded to show that for _these_ particular odd functions the expectations are zero and so the empirical mean and variance are uncorrelated?