# Deriving covariance of sample mean and sample variance

Tags: probability, statistics

$\newcommand{\cov}{\operatorname{cov}}$I want to find the covariance between the sample mean and the sample variance, I think I am along the right track but am not sure.

Suppose we have i.i.d. random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$.

Define

$$\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \text{ and } S^2 = \frac{1}{2n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (X_i - X_j)^2 $$

I want to find their covariance $\cov(\overline{X}, S^2)$. Here is what I have done:

\begin{align}
& \cov(\overline{X}, S^2) = \cov\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \frac{1}{2n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (X_i - X_j)^2 \right) \\
= {} & \frac{1}{2n^2(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \cov(X_i,\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} (X_k - X_j)^2) \\
= {} & \frac{1}{2n^2(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^n \cov(X_i,2\sum_{k=1}^{n} (X_i - X_k)^2)
\end{align}

(because $\cov(X_i, (X_a - X_b)^2)$ is zero if $i$ isn't $a$ or $b$)

$$= \frac{1}{n^2(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \cov(X_i, (X_i - X_k)^2).$$

Now, I compute $\cov(X_i, (X_i - X_k)^2)$:

for $ i = k, \cov(X_i, (X_i - X_k)^2) = 0$

for $ i \neq k,$

\begin{align}
& \cov(X_i, (X_i - X_k)^2) = \cov(X_i, X_i^2 - 2X_iX_k + X_k^2) = \cov(X_i, X_i^2) - 2\cov(X_i, X_iX_k) \\[8pt]
= {} & E(X^3) - E(X)E(X^2) -2E(X)E(X^2) + 2(E(X))^3 \\[8pt]
= {} & E(X^3) -3E(X)E(X^2) + 2(E(X))^3.
\end{align}

When I plug this in, I do not get the answer that I want which is $E(X-E(X))^3$, can anyone please tell me where I went wrong?

UPDATE: I plugged it in again and it is actually correct! Sorry for being so careless. Thanks to anyone who has read the question. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Does $\operatorname E(X-\operatorname E(X))^3$ mean $(\operatorname E(X-\operatorname E(X)))^3$ or $\operatorname E((X-\operatorname E(X))^3) \text{ ?}$ I would guess the latter, but I prefer being explicit about this.

Comment: In more conventional notation, $S^2$ often denotes $\displaystyle \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \big( X_i -\overline X \,\big)^2.$ I haven't checked whether your notation agrees with that, but can you tell us whether you intended it to be the same thing? $\qquad$

Comment: $E(X - E(X))^3$ means $E((X - E(X))^3)$.

Comment: Yes, my book also uses $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \overline X)^2$, but the first part of the exercise is actually to show that $S^2 = \frac{1}{2n(n-1)} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (X_i - X_j)^2$, so they are equal.

Comment: Since they are equal, why not use the simpler form?

Comment: Because I thought that the other form would be simpler for this particular question. Maybe the conventional form would make things easier. At this point I am more interested in where I went wrong than in solving the actual problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80018/discussion-between-noppawee-apichonpongpan-and-michael-hardy).

Comment: Doesn't it look like I am close to the solution?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235634/how-to-find-the-covariance-of-sample-mean-and-sample-variance-covm-s2-for-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) post ought to answer your question. We have the result $$\operatorname{Cov}(\bar X,S^2)=\frac{\mu_3}{n}$$ for a random sample $(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ of size $n$, provided $\mu_3$, the population central moment of order $3$ exists.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you. I have seen alternative solutions online. However, I am curious as to why my derivative is incorrect.